# PyTorch unfold vs as_stride

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

It seems PyTorch `unfold` and `as_stride` are doing the same thing but for the former, you cannot control the tensor output size.

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

x = torch.arange(0, 10)

x1 = x.unfold(0, 3, 1)

x2 = x.as_strided((8,3), (1,1))

print(f'x1 = {x1}')
print(f'x2 = {x2}')
```

```py
output:
x1 = tensor([[0, 1, 2],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [2, 3, 4],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [5, 6, 7],
        [6, 7, 8],
        [7, 8, 9]])
x2 = tensor([[0, 1, 2],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [2, 3, 4],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [5, 6, 7],
        [6, 7, 8],
        [7, 8, 9]])
```

Then is there any situation that you should use `unfold` instead of `as_stride` and vice versa?

Comment: I think `unfold` might be intended as an easier version "to get right" than `as_strided`. However there is some discussion here https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/60466 that `as_strided` might be faster than `unfold`.